# How to hide / show a component according to the current component?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am something new in angular, and know the answer my problem I am sure that it will make me learn a lot. in my default component the `MainComponent` is loaded in my `<router-outlet>`, at this level both the `menu` and the `footer` are displayed. I want **ONLY** to show up when I'm in any component that is **NOT** `MainComponent` in my case in `AnotherComponent` should be shown, but if I go back to `MainComponent` it will not. How can I do this? I've tried with `ngIf` and it does not work for me (I think it goes beyond this)

this is part of my code:

```
<menu (setAnimal)='setAnimal($event)' ></menu>
<router-outlet (activate)='onActivate($event)'></router-outlet>
```

```
@Component({
  selector: 'main',
  template: '<div><a routerLink="/another">anotherComponent</a></div>',
  styles: [`div {
      position: fixed;
      min-width: 100%;
      background-image: url("https://source.unsplash.com/1920x1080?stars") !important;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: 100%;
    background-position: center;
      background-size: cover;
}`]
})

  @Component({
    selector: 'another',
    template: '<div><a routerLink="/">main</a></div>',
    styles: [`div {
      position: fixed;
      min-width: 100%;
      background-image: url("https://source.unsplash.com/1920x1080?landscape") !important;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: 100%;
      background-position: center;
      background-size: cover;
      }`]
  })
```

this is my live code:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qcxnln

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand well, if you inject the router in your AppComponent:

```
constructor(private router: Router){
    router.events.subscribe(e => {
    if(e instanceof NavigationEnd){
      if(e.urlAfterRedirects != '/'){
        this.headerFooterVisible= true;
      }else{
        this.headerFooterVisible= false;
      }

    }
  });
```

You could subscribe to the route events and so check if you are in the root path.
Then with a couple of ngIf:

```
<menu (setAnimal)='setAnimal($event)' *ngIf="headerFooterVisible"></menu>
<router-outlet (activate)='onActivate($event)'></router-outlet>
<footer *ngIf="headerFooterVisible"></footer>
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ufdkjy?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: thanks, it almost works, but if I go back to MainComponent, the footer and the menu are loaded .. they should never be loaded in the MainComponent

Answer (score 0):

get the component name in `onActivate` hook of `router-outlet` using `obj.constructor.name` and compare accordingly.

working sample = https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r8pnot

Answer (score 0):

you can put Menu and Footer in Another Component, make this as an page template. For the pages you want to display like Another component (display menu and footer), use 'children'

```
 const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: MainComponent },
    { 
      path: 'another',
      component: AnotherComponent,
      children: [
         path: 'something',
         component: SomeComponent
      ]
  }
];
```